# javascript to hide a div if empty

Tags: javascript

I am looking for javascript (not jquery as client has specified) to hide a div with class=top, if the div has no content. I can do it using jquery like below, but need to use javascript. Any ideas please?

```
$('div.top:empty').hide();
```

Comment: Your client specified it but you're not going to use it?

Comment: @j08691 He's saying he needs to use javascript to accomplish what that one jQuery statement does

Comment: If he's using jQuery elsewhere, then this is useless, FYI

Comment: Define "no content".  Do you mean no tags, no white space, no (visible) text strings, etc?  e.g. is `<div class="top"><b> </b></div>` empty, or not?  What if the space is removed?

Comment: Is there any reason preventing your client from using jquery?

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf the client specified not to use jQuery - that's reason enough.

Comment: I'm not saying he should or shouldn't use it, I'm just curious.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
var top = document.getElementsByClassName("top");
for (var i = 0; i < top.length; i++) {
    if (top[i].innerHTML.length == 0)
        top[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use `innerHTML` property to check if the selected `div.top` element contains content. something like this.

```
var topDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('top')[0];
if(topDiv.innerHTML === '') {
    topDiv.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(if(document.getElementById("yourDiv").innerHTML=="")
{
  document.getElementById("yourDiv").style.display='none';
}
```

Comment: I mean empty like <div class="top"></div>

Comment: Also, if I have say four divs - top, left, right and bottom, how could I have one piece of code to do the same function for all four divs? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. The div could have whitespace in it.

Comment: That's not a problem, you could use `trim`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following script:

```
var divContent = $('div .top')[0].innerHTML;

if (divContent === '')
{
    $('div .top').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to give id to DIV** which you want to hide As there are no function in javascript by which you can find div by class. 
HTML:

```
<div class="top" id="divId"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
if( document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML == "" )
{
   document.getElementById("divId").style.display='none';
}
```

Comment: <style>  
#top
{
padding: 0;
height: 120px;
width: 820px;
float: left;
background: #cccccc;
}
</style>
  <script>
if( document.getElementById("top").innerHTML == "" )
{
   document.getElementById("top").style.display='none';
}
  </script>
  <div id="top">
  </div>

Comment: Hello,
You need to trim the innerHtml string like


    trim(document.getElementById("top").innerHTML)
    function trim(str) {
          return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
    }